# Docker image corruption? Remove layers?

Tags: docker, containers

After a system restart, it looks like the docker images which were existing are corrupted.

I tried the following-

1. Rebuild a docker inside that machine - this worked. This image is running fine.
2. I pulled an image which was already existing, it said layers already exist. But this image still seems to be corrupted.

I feel that removing the image will help. When I try removing, it seems to remove only the tag. It is not removing all the layers. How can I do this?

I tried `docker rmi`. The image got removed.

Now, I try to pull the image again, some of the layers are already existing. I am trying to run the docker, it says `oci runtime error ..... file not found`.

These images are working on other machines, and was working on this machine till some hours before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Stop docker service
2. Remove /var/lib/docker
3. Start docker service

Comment: The only problem with this is that I have containers I want to keep running and this will wipe out me installation entirely!

Comment: This is crazy, I have a seemingly corrupted layer which means I cannot do a successful pull, and cannot remove it as the image does not exist. This answer seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 10):

**Warn** :
Deleting some directories of `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` may look appealing, may work but it is also risky. Indeed, it may create additional inconsistency/corrupted layers.
If you do that, please first make a full backup of folders that you want delete.
I did it two times in a production environment. The first time it worked, the second time it provoked a real mess (hard time and stress to fix that).
Since, I never did it again.

To fix issues with image pulling (layer not found or corrupted), here my tricks.

**1 - If you **may** and **want** to wipe all your images and containers, you could do that.**

Stop and remove all containers (running or not) :

```
docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -aq))
```

And in addition, use the [system prune command](http://%20%20%20%20docker%20system%20prune%20--volume%20--all) :

```
docker system prune --volumes --all
```

to delete :

- all stopped containers
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all volumes not used by at least one container
- all images without at least one container associated to them
- all build cache

To skip the confirmation dialog, add the `-f` flag.

It should solve corrupted layer issues since you restart from scratch.

**2 - If it doesn't work (that is layers are still not found or corrupted), a possible strategy is ensuring that these failing layers are not used any longer during the pull.**

To achieve that :

- If the problem is a parent image layer : I update the base image specified in the Dockerfile to find a base image version which the layer(s) with the issue is not used any longer.
  Generally I specify a little more recent version, I build/run.
  If if works, fine.
  If it still fails, I update the base image version further.
- If the problem is an image layer created in my Dockerfile steps itself : I specify the **--no-cache** flag in docker build.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `docker images -a` options to know all the images with layers.To know particular layers of particular images you can use `docker history $image_name`

Also there is a option to remove dangling images by which you can delete it.

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

Dangling images:

Docker images consist of multiple layers. Dangling images are layers that have no relationship to any tagged images. They no longer serve a purpose and consume disk space. They can be located by adding the filter flag, `-f` with a value of `dangling=true` to the docker images command. When you're sure you want to delete them, you can add the `-q` flag, then pass their ID to docker rmi:

Hope this will help you. Thank you!

Comment: docker images -f dangling=true doesn't seem to list layers. Franco's answer seems to be the only usable answer

Answer (score 0):

[Docker rmi](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi) should remove all the images layer's from your machine. You can try forcing it with:

`docker rmi --force [IMAGE]`

Comment: I tried `docker rmi`. The image got removed.
Now, I try to pull the image again, some of the layers are already existing. 
I am trying to run the docker, it says `oci runtime error ..... file not found`.
These images are working on other machines, and was working on this machine till some hours before.

Comment: Is your issue now resolved? Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the exact same issue (node:latest in my case)

Here is what I did, after encountering the same issue:

```
[root@container1 docker]# docker rmi -f node:latest
Untagged: node:latest
Untagged: node@sha256:908e8182394cb5672465780ed45512d9b78dccd10d674e84158ea65b40bba755
[root@container1 docker]# docker pull node:latest
latest: Pulling from library/node
Digest: sha256:908e8182394cb5672465780ed45512d9b78dccd10d674e84158ea65b40bba755
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
```

^^ This is what we got stuck on

But turns out, when the docker image was attempting to build, there is a residual image:

```
[root@container1 containers]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS               NAMES
a3af68deafbd        4c144cb53d02                           "/bin/sh -c 'sed -i …"   5 minutes ago       Created                                              flamboyant_keller
```

So delete that edge container:

```
[root@container1 containers]# docker rm a3af68deafbd
a3af68deafbd
```

and then remove the image in force

```
[root@container1 containers]# docker rmi -f node:latest
Untagged: node:latest
Untagged: node@sha256:908e8182394cb5672465780ed45512d9b78dccd10d674e84158ea65b40bba755
Deleted: sha256:451b716593e5f4b35826c8f869950135b925e74d0ed0a40b7c794b8a54ce9b39
Deleted: sha256:a03d77a43b5351b97ef19f81c840533ff6422114700b1681ee7c151a832fb87c
Deleted: sha256:e6a6066bc15756135253b5fe918000872498a3a3ac32f0bf2bce09536268778c
Deleted: sha256:fbe47ce144caf697d31353941e02e3fb3595c8ecb90cc3d9267a491abd7aa6a7
Deleted: sha256:8d8dabce32d508dfcd126ab43cde7b690764c4bd06800e7cac816d367473ad3e
Deleted: sha256:addff6454b75bcccc23ba0cdbf9ff5d83f6df71523cd3428261d1785c3e3c592
Deleted: sha256:dae4f674403b331cb8c19b2c238ffa7d5a7249a1b4fafc4725054201dce3341a
Deleted: sha256:a9a9c8853295275070975beba78ec0f573172e6e41b30232a00d8af0d49b8ef3
Deleted: sha256:ddf0293e8e23246803d265b158ffbb9453d925fe392b43515984815853e9121b
Deleted: sha256:f94641f1fe1f5c42c325652bf55f0513c881c86b620b912b15460e0bca07cc12


[root@container1 containers]# docker pull node:latest
latest: Pulling from library/node
c5e155d5a1d1: Pull complete
221d80d00ae9: Pull complete
4250b3117dca: Pull complete
3b7ca19181b2: Pull complete
425d7b2a5bcc: Pull complete
69df12c70287: Pull complete
2c4b8b667e51: Pull complete
6a284be89e14: Pull complete
9b005e913bed: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:908e8182394cb5672465780ed45512d9b78dccd10d674e84158ea65b40bba755
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
```

And there you go

Answer (score 0):

In my case `docker image ls -a` did not list my image which was corrupted by power failure. I could not pull the image or delete it properly. So I fixed it by pulling the image to another machine, saving it to a file with

> docker image save -o /tmp/layers111

then used

> docker image load -i /tmp/layers111

as it complained that the file already existed I renamed them with suffix _old and repeated that until all layers were copied/loaded. Then `docker images` displayed the corrrupt image plus the image I loaded with incremented name and version! All is now running