# How to refresh all layers of an image from dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I had some data corruption on my disk due to a misconfigured backup.
This has corrupted some of of the intermediate layers.

Is there a command to verify the integrity(checksum?) of all docker data (volumes, Images, Layers etc)?

Once an corrupted layer is found how do a force a pull of that layer from dockerhub?

Comment: You could stop the Docker daemon, delete all of `/var/lib/docker`, and start over.  It sounds like you're already in a position where the volume data needs to be recovered from backups, you should be able to pull or rebuild all of the images, and nothing valuable should be in the container temporary filesystems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker image corruption? Remove layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974865/docker-image-corruption-remove-layers)

Comment: No it does not, This is on a production system where a few images are corrupted and rest and working fine. We cannot afford downtime on the working infrastructure :(

Answer (score -1):

Try rebuild the image whilst ignoring the cache:

```bash
% docker build --no-cache
```

[docker build docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Comment: This has no effect on potentially-corrupted base images, or any part of the Docker storage beyond one immediate image build.

Comment: Ok, if this doesn't work you could remove the docker image locally (`docker image rm <image name>`) then pull the image fresh from docker hub and rebuild. Again I would ignore the cache when rebuilding.

Comment: Does not work. I will have to delete all layers of the image manually which can cause issues with other images which share some of the (non-corrupted)layers.